# RequestMapping not working

Tags: java, spring

I build a Spring project with netbean and got some problem.

I simply put a form and a submit input which supposed to be processed by StudentController but I got 404 when the button is clicked.
Am I doing something wrong?

**index.jsp**

```
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="student">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

**StudentController.java**

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/student",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView student(){
    return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
}
}
```

**web.xml**(Generate by NetBean)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**(Generate by NetBean)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
</beans>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**(Generate by NetBean)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
</beans>
```

Sorry for posting all the codes here, because I have really no idea where will the problem be.  Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried "http://localhost:8080/Student/index.htm" 
and it's fine, but after click submit, URL is "http://localhost:8080/Student/student" and I got 404.

Comment: I just want to go to another page and don't know how to specify method with <a href=...>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Spring servlet is mapped to `*.htm`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But your form sends a request to `/student`. `*.htm` doesn't match `/student`, so obviously, you get a 404.

Comment: Could you tell me how should I do?

Comment: should I request /student.htm?

Comment: Yes, or you should change your mapping to /, to have *every* request sent to the dispatcher servlet. If you choose the first solution, then the URL in the RequestMapping should also be `/student.htm`.

Comment: If you choose the first solution, then the URL in the RequestMapping should also be /student.htm. And you also need a `/WEB-INF/jsp/student.jsp` file.

Comment: I tried `action="student.htm"` and `@RequestMapping(value = "/student.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET)`. Also I have a `/WEB-INF/jsp/student.jsp` file. But still in vain...Orz

Comment: What is the URL displayed in the address bar on the 404 error page?

Comment: I'm not used to XML configuration of Spring, but I think your configuration is outdated and doesn't enable annotations. I would do everything with annotations, and thus remove ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping and urlMapping and indexController from the file, and simply replace it by `<mvc:annotation-driven />` (the mvc namespace must be declared. Check the documentation). Also make sure to have a `<context:component-scan ...>` element so that your controller beans are detected by Spring.

Comment: I tried 
  `<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>`
  `<context:component-scan base-package="Controller"></context:component-scan>`
But I can't access index.htm anymore.

Comment: The package of your controllers is "Controller"? That doesn't look like a conventional package name to me. Packages are normally all lower-case, and of the form `com.mycompany.myapp.controllers`.

Comment: OK. So I tried `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myapp.controllers"></context:component-scan>` but still can't access `index.htm`...

Comment: After doing what you said, I add a method in StudentController:
    `@RequestMapping(value="/index.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }`
And the problem fixed! Thank you very much, I'll post my solution as answer and accept you answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is beacause the dispatcher servlet only listens on `.htm` requests, but you request `localhost:8080/Student/student`.

Try

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: If I do so, I get an error:
  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]

Comment: @nosnhoj sorry my fault. I mean `/*`

Comment: Thank you, but once I tried `/*`, I can't even access index.jsp(which is accessible before) and get 404.

Comment: @nosnhoj try `index.htm`, because you mapped it in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` to the `indexController` which is a `ParameterizableViewController` and thus should handle the request.

Comment: @nosnhoj one moment I try to get it run on my machine.

Comment: @nosnhoj Sorry have to stop working now. But here are some things to mention. First use `/` instead of `/*` in the servlet mappting. Than take a look a `context:component-scan` for the controller to register and make sure that the `index.jsp` is located in `WEB-INF/jsp` as you defined in the `InternalResourceViewResolver`. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you very much for spending so much time here!

Answer (score 0):

Advised by @JB Nizet, I removed

1. `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`
2. `urlMapping`
3. `indexController`

from the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file, and simply replaced it by `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

What's more, `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myapp.controllers"></context:component-scan>` was add to the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file.

Also, you need to specify `xsi:schemaLocation`, so add

"`http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd`"

to the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute.

And after all of these, I edited `index.jsp` to : (make student as student.htm)

```
    <form method="GET" action="student.htm">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

And simply wrote those in my StudentController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(){
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/student.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView student(){
    return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
}
```

After those, the problem was fixed.
Maybe I should consider useing Eclipse instead of NetBean to build Spring.

Comment: BTW, I'm using NetBeans 7.3.1